# Android simply 3 x 3 image button grid

Tags: android, android-layout

new to developing with android 
but im looking for some help in finding a way to create a simply 3 x 3 image button grid similar to example below but with a 3 rows and 3 columns with an image button wrapping its content in its assign squre [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T414r.jpg)

but no matter what i do i cant get the columns and rows to evenly spread out both in weight and height

so im looking for some help in what the best way i can do this any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/Main_Menu_Grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your xml so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can set attribute in gridview

```
android:numColumns="3"
```

Comment: even when i set the column number they still all bunch up in the top left corner  where as i want them evenly spaced out over the layout

Comment: any ideas on how i can achieve my desired layout?